# Text View with Suggestion list

Tags: android, sqlite, android-edittext

I am new to Android that's why getting a problem in very starting phase.
I have to submit this project in my college. Actually in my project I want a EditText with suggestion in a List. Like If I am writing 'L' in Text Box then it shows all the city name starting with 'L' or I have written 'K' then it'll show all the names starting with 'K' in a list.All the city names will be in Local database (SQLite).

Sorry If i am not cleared with my question.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use AutoCompleteTextView? A little google will give you plenty of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

activity_main.xml:

Drag the AutoCompleteTextView and TextView from the pallete, now the activity_main.xml file will like this:

> File: activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:androclass="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >  

    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/textView1"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"  
        android:text="@string/what_is_your_favourite_programming_language_" />  

    <AutoCompleteTextView  
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"  
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"  
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"  
        android:ems="10"  
        android:text="">  

        <requestFocus />  
    </AutoCompleteTextView>  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity class

Let's write the code of AutoCompleteTextView.

File: MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.autocompletetextview;  

import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.graphics.Color;  
import android.view.Menu;  
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;  
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;  

public class MainActivity extends Activity {  
    String[] language ={"C","C++","Java",".NET","iPhone","Android","ASP.NET","PHP"};  
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

        //Creating the instance of ArrayAdapter containing list of language names  
           ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>  
            (this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,language);  
        //Getting the instance of AutoCompleteTextView  
           AutoCompleteTextView actv= (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);  
           actv.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character  
           actv.setAdapter(adapter);//setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView  
           actv.setTextColor(Color.RED);  

    }  

    @Override  
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.  
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);  
        return true;  
    }  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

This is what you need. The example in the documentation pulls the suggestions from an array, but it shouldn't be that hard to figure out how to connect it to your data source.